# Multi level nested association shortcuts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models, model-associations

I'm having trouble with associations. Basically, Users have groups (not shared with anybody). Each group has clients, projects and tasks.

Should I define something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :groups 
  has_many :clients, through: :groups
  has_many :projects, through :clients #(could be groups?) 
  has_many :task, through :groups 
end
```

is this the proper way of doing it? I just want, from each user, list all their task, groups and clients. Is it ok to 'travel' through the models like this?
 I've followed some RoR tutorials and books, but all of them deal with less models.

[basic rough model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZqsa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate **through** like you want. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) is explained the case when you want a **shortcut** through nested `has_many` associations (search a little below the link I posted).

So given this explanation, for this to work you need to do the following (you were close to it):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups 
  has_many :clients, through: :groups
  has_many :projects, through :groups
  has_many :tasks, through :groups 
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :clients
  has_many :projects, through :clients
  has_many :tasks, through :clients 
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group

  has_many :projects
  has_many :tasks, through :projects 
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client

  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Another way (and maybe shorter) to set this up would be (look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Nested+Associations) for where both strategies are documented):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups 
  has_many :clients, through: :groups
  has_many :projects, through :clients
  has_many :tasks, through :projects 
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :clients
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group

  has_many :projects
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client

  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks!, that was what I wanted. I was just afraid it wasn't the correct way. I appreciate your answer :D

Comment: @Gaston sure, np! If you are satisfied and you think it's the correct answer, please mark it as the correct answer :)